# Install Base Percentage difference between Firebase and GooglePlayConsole

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-console

Since few weeks, we constat a gap between Firebase and Google Play console for the Application version install base.

In Firebase -> Latest Release, we can see 22.91% active user

[image]

In Playstore -> Production -> Install Base, we can see 68.71%

[image]

In recent past, it was the same percentage between both plateform

It is normal this sudent gap since few weeks since Playstore and Firebase ?
May Firebase have changed calculation formula ?